# Как в BottomSheet удержать кнопку постоянно видимой

Tags: java, android, material-design, bottom-sheet

Как в `BottomSheet` удержать кнопку видимой в любом состоянии? Для примера приложение ВКонтакте: когда в сообщении прикрепляем какое-то фото, открывается `BottomSheet` и, кнопка отмена/добавить всегда видна внизу при любом состоянии `BottomSheet`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приложите к вопросу скриншоты или рисунки, того о чем вы спрашиваете. Не все имеют или захотят устанавливать какое-то приложение ВКонтакте, чтобы понять, о чем вы говорите

Comment: @pavlofff добавил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче, там просто у них сделан нестед скролл вью  в фрейм лаяуте и на верх просто кнопка винизу вот и весь фокус :)